# How can i use multiple(not single) client certificates to login in with cypress?

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress, client-certificates

Can we use multiple client certificates for login purpose. For ex: I need to login application as abc@xyz.comand then again i need to login as efg@xyz.com. So is it possible to login as multiple user using certificates?

I have successfully configured for one client certificate and successfully logged in. but not able to find a solution for multiple logins with different user ids? Looking forward for a solution

I stored certificates in cert folder and link it in cypress.config file and it worked for a single certificate.

Answer (score 4):

The Cypress configuration does support multiple certificates, but it is on a per-URL basis not on a per-User basis.

See [Client Certificates](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/client-certificates)

```js
module.exports = defineConfig({
  clientCertificates: [
    {
      url: 'https://a.host.com',
      ca: ['certs/ca.pem'],
      certs: [
        {
          ...
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      url: 'https://b.host.com/a_base_route/**',
      ca: [],
      certs: [
        {
          ...
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      url: 'https://a.host.*.com/',
      ca: [],
      certs: [
        {
          ...
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
})
```

This may be enough to solve your problem, just adding all the certificates into the array, but I suspect not so.

Instead, you may need to change the certificate dynamically in the test.

- add the certificates to a `certificates.json` file
- add a `user` property to each certificate
- at some point in the test change the certificate

**File for certifiactes - `certificates.json`**

```js
{
  clientCertificates: [
    {
      user: 'Sandy', 
      url: 'https://a.host.com',
      ca: ['certs/ca.pem'],
      certs: [
        {
          ...
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      user: 'Mandy', 
      url: 'https://b.host.com/a_base_route/**',
      ca: [],
      certs: [
        {
          ...
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      user: 'Randy', 
      url: 'https://a.host.*.com/',
      ca: [],
      certs: [
        {
          ...
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

**Dynamically changing the certificate**

```js
const certificates = require('certificates.json')

it('Tests with certificate for Randy', () => {

  const userCert = Cypress._.find(certificates, { 'user': 'Randy' })
  const configCert = Cypress._.omit(userCert , ['user'])   
  Cypress.config('clientCertificates', [ configCert ])

  ...
```

This is the gist of the code, you can modify in various ways, e.g make a custom command in `cypress/support/e2e.js` to make it one line in each test or at the top of a suite (inside a `describe()`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Paolo. But a bit confused again,  Is it possible to use different certificates for the same url?  
I am trying to implement an E2E test using cypress and client cert authentication, and need more than one pair of client certificate to verify different use cases under the same site and don't know how or if it's possible to choose specifically one pair at runtime.
We have different client certificates for manager roles and member roles, and we need to pick the corresponding certificate at a test case level or at least at spec level.  @Paolo

Comment: No worries, you can add as many certificates per user in `certificates.json` as you want as it's free-format. The code to load into config may be different.

Comment: If you put a concrete example in the question, I'll give you the code, but the principle remains the same.

Comment: The only thing you might have trouble with is the Cypress lodash `Cypress._` methods. Worth your while practicing those to gain general skills for extracting data from fixtures.